# Is ssh_from necessary in parallelcluster config?

Tags: networking, security, amazon-web-services

On the AWS [parallelcluster blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/aws-parallelcluster/) they recommend using ssh_from in the parallelcluster config:

> By default, we will allow SSH inbound from any source IP (0.0.0.0/0),
>   and I want to restrict this to just my IP address. I recommend that
>   you do something similar by adding your IP address or trusted CIDR
>   block (e.g. 10.10.0.0/16).

However, I still need to use a key-pair to access my headnode, so is the ssh_from necessary? What added benefit does it provide?

Answer (score 0):

Security is built up in layers.

By limiting SSH to only your system(s) it cuts down the surface area to protect -

if an attacker can not even see SSH then it means they can't attack it. This prevents wasted  resources answering and failing to negotiate an encrypted connection and mitigates against potential flaws in SSH and leaked keys.

If you are willing to put all of these risks aside then you can open SSH to the world - it's just not a best practice.